# Printing char* resulting in segmentation fault?

Tags: c, gcc, char

The following program results in segmentation fault [I have used gcc as compiler], How to print str in the character pointer and why segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOW 0x40000000
#define HIGH 0x0

int main()
{
 volatile char* str = (char*) (HIGH + LOW);
 printf ( "Character Str:%s",str);  
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to use absolute addressing.  So you need to ensure that (1) 0x40000000 is mapped and readable, and (2) you need to ensure that you encounter a zero byte to terminate the "string" you expect to find.  I'd start by attempting to print a single byte rather than a null-terminated string.

Comment: Because there isn't a string at 0x40000000?

Comment: @immibis I would expect a null since there is no string can you elaborate?

Comment: You cannot expect nothing about what is stored at that address. Is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). As @TomKarzes wrote are you sure that `0x40000000` is a memory address? Could be a uP register or something else on the memory map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the pointer `str` to point to an absolute memory address, memory address `0x40000000`. The `(char*)` cast is why your compiler isn't complaining. There is almost certainly nothing useful at that address because you haven't declared anything besides that pointer. Don't use absolute memory addressing unless you're writing an operating system or are coding for a legacy system without virtual memory for each program. Even then it's a bad idea if you don't know what you're doing.

`printf` is failing because you're telling it look for a valid string starting at the memory pointed to by `ptr` and print it out to stdout (e.g. your console). In the highly unlikely event that address `0x40000000` is readable by your process at the time of execution and it contains a valid, null-terminated string, it would print something out without the segfault. It would still be gibberish.

Based on the number you chose for `HIGH`, it looks like you were trying to null-terminate a string. If you wanted to create a string that `printf` could print you might try something like this:

```
char str[12] = "Hello World";
printf ( "Character Str:%s",str);
```

Once that was properly allocated, you could could create a pointer and work with that if you so desired.

```
char *strptr = str;
printf ( "Character StrPtr:%s",strptr);
```

I may be way off base on what you were actually trying to do. But what you are doing is not valid, and what you are trying to do is not obvious.